# Trying to add "idempotency_key" to stripe payment intent. Not showing up in the array after submitting to stripe. Is there something wrong?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The request is successfully sent, but when I check the content of the request, the indempotency value is not in the array, Do I have a syntax error or am I doing something wrong?

```
    $idempotency_key = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
  $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => $price,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'customer' => ''.$_SESSION['uid'].'',
    'payment_method' => ''.$payid.'',
    'description' => ''.$title.'',
    "metadata" => [
        'task' => ''.$_POST['pid'].'',
        'offer' => ''.$_POST['accept'].'',
        'category' => ''.$category.'',
        'location' => ''.$location.''
    ],  
    'off_session' => false,
    'confirm' => true,
    'confirmation_method' => 'automatic',
    'use_stripe_sdk' => true,
      ], [
  "idempotency_key" => ''.$idempotency_key.'',
  ]);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by it's not in the array? You wouldn't see the idempotency key represented on the PaymentIntent object, as it's a part of the request only (which you can see in your Dashboard request logs).

Comment: Try put this idempotency_key inside the second array, as a seconde parameter